# Обрезка изображения по четырем точкам

Tags: php

Интересует возможность обрезки изображения средствами PHP по четырем координатам. Если вырезать прямоугольную/квадратную область - все понятно. А вот как реализовать обрезку именно по четырем точкам, чтобы в итоге могла вырезаться фигура произвольной формы?

Заранее благодарю. Единственное, что приходит пока в голову - это использовать какую-то маску и накладывать ее на изображение, но это уже на фронте делать. А вот как такое с помощью php сделать - вопрос...

Comment: Закрась ненужные части.